# How to read a custom Json Object from a String

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson Library to read Json. I have a Json Object that is not always the same, so I can't define a class with particular properties.

I want to read it as a `String` and later split and manipulate it as a `Map<K,V>`.

Below is my object.

I want the `row` filed to be converted to a `String` while reading.

```
{
   "data":{
      "sampleTime":"2017-12-08T02:24:26.334Z",
      "target":{
         "gateway":"TRADPRT_OTPLTP_GDCE",
         "probe":"HKLGISWAS02B-7102",
         "managedEntity":"HKLGISWAS02B-7102",
         "type":"Core_Linux",
         "sampler":"Disk",
         "dataview":"Disk",
         "filter":{
            "osType":"Linux",
            "pluginName":"DISK"
         }
      },
      "name":"freeSpace",
      "row":{
         "/":"5806 MB",
         "/sys":"0 MB",
         "/dev/pts":"0 MB",
         "/dev/shm":"64475 MB",
         "/boot":"28 MB",
         "/home":"6775 MB",
         "/opt":"5971 MB",
         "/tmp":"4287 MB",
         "/u/operator":"277 MB",
         "/usr/controlm":"3665 MB",
         ...
         "/apps/S2B/WBDS":"11249 MB"
      }
   },
   "operation":"update"
}
```

Comment: so ... what is the question?

Comment: Its is not a valid JSON.Just validated in JSONLINT.Please provide the correct JSON for correct output.

Comment: @mckuok : Help me to convert 'Row' object to a String when I am reading the Json file.

Comment: @mohorchatt : done . I am only looking for the Row Object to be converted to String. Thanks

Comment: What is this Row object you're talking about? Why can't you use toString() over the JSONObject?

Comment: you mean to read only the Row object as string and do some processing on it?can you just add the desired output you want.If clarified this can be done

Comment: If you don't mind I'll edit your question a little to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex JSON can be represented as `Map<String, Object>`, where the `Object` can also be a `Map<String, Object>`, and so on. (If I understand your question correctly)

Then you can call

```
Map<String, Object> o = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

to convert a JSON string to a `Map`